# Why I can not inastall some R packages on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: r, installation

I have tried this:

> install.packages("fields")
>   Warning in install.packages("fields") :
>    argument 'lib' is missing: using '/home/milenko/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.10'
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
>
> Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
>
> Warning message:
>   In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
>     package ‘fields’ is not available

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running R-2.10.X and the latest [fields on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fields/) (as of today) requires R-3.0 or greater. Either install an older version of the package from source, or upgrade your 4+ year-old version of R.